# Google Client API

Tags: java, android, api, google-play-games, multiplayer

I have some simple questions:

I'm starting to use [google client API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/) to make multiplayer games and the main question here is:

1- using google client API - RealTime Multiplayer, the server-side coding needs to be 'abstracted', meaning that everyone is a client and everyone is a server at the same time. So if I use this API, do I need to make one of the players the host of the multiplayer game, and thus the 'server' of the game, is that correct?

2- what about if I need to make updates inside the application without changing the app release version. In other words, assuming that I need to keep sending new items, or unlockables over the time to the game, without updating the full app, is there any way that this API can aproach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You apps will work as client,   the google server is managin the real time messages,  finally the apps receive notification events when the other point send real time message.
2. The most basic is that you build a new apk with the logics of you new achievements, and add these achievement to google play game proyect, google only let add new achievements you are responsable of update you apk.  Otherwise, you would need kind of backend that let support that updates every time that you add new achievements.

Comment: Thanks, for the second point, im saying for instance: 

I publish an rpg game with a limited number of weapons on it, but over time I want to deliver more new weapons and items to the users unlock and achieve (like an inside update), how can I do this using google Services API? If its even possible?

Answer (score 0):

The realtime multiplayer game API (RTMP) actually establishes a mesh of connections between the players.  This way the communication is direct as possible vs having to go to a server each time.  See https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer for more details.

Since all the players are peers, there is no need for one player to "host" the virtual room.  Once the players are connected, they can send and receive messages without central coordination.  See the sample https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/ButtonClicker for examples on the skeleton of a multi-player game.

The second part of your question seems unrelated to RTMP and a little vague, but if I understand your question, you can have multiple versions of apps playing in the  same multiplayer game as long as they are associated with the same Play Game services game.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I wanted to state that in this case using p2p connections, if I need a central controller for the purpose of avoiding different outcomes in each client due to the delay of the connection, etc..., I still need a host right? Ex: In a racing game, if I need to check who finnished first I need to have a central controler to keep tracking each player's position, if each one checked its own, I could have delayed or diferent outcomes on each results, like having 3 winners at first place. And thats why I need to have a central controller, a host! Correct?

Comment: Not necessarily.  Check out this article series on developing a real time racing game with Play Services.  It has answers to a lot of questions like this. http://www.raywenderlich.com/86040/creating-cross-platform-multiplayer-game-unity-part-1